# ruby active model serializer association on version > 0.8.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

How do I get this relation to work with the new version?

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids
  attributes :id, :email, :created_at, :updated_at, :auth_token

  has_many :products
end
```

works with

```
gem "active_model_serializers", "~> 0.8.0"
```

but, doesn't work with

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', git: "https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers.git"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think theay are working on a new version which breaks the old, ones, so you better stick to `0.8.0` or `0.9.0` at least for now.

For more information about this check out https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#maintenance-please-read